gradle version incompatible or java version error
im creating flutter project and i found this error in android studio that is gradel Issu error is showing this
Launching lib\main.dart on RMX2151 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open cp_settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\untitled\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\HP\.gradle\caches\7.6\scripts\1xnftno0sh94ll65ky75jq782).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 65

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 856ms

┌─ Flutter Fix ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using   │
│ for Gradle.                                                                                     │
│                                                                                                 │
│ If you recently upgraded Android Studio, consult the migration guide at                         │
│ docs.flutter.dev/go/android-java-gradle-error.                                                  │
│                                                                                                 │
│ Otherwise, to fix this issue, first, check the Java version used by Flutter by running `flutter │
│ doctor --verbose`.                                                                              │
│                                                                                                 │
│ Then, update the Gradle version specified in                                                    │
│ C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\untitled\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to  │
│ be compatible with that Java version. See the link below for more information on compatible     │
│ Java/Gradle versions:                                                                           │
│ https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java                               │
│                                                                                                 │
│                                                                                                 │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

i try to do changis as chatgtp told me now still this error still avilable in my project even i changed an url in gradel wrapeer prperti but still im seen this error
im using java 17 and fpr gradel url distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip
can someon do explain solve this error

This issue is mainly due to new update of Android Studio LadyBug that makes it incompatible to run with java-21. To resolve this, refer to Flutter 3.24.3 problem with Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1
